# IJCADでGetPoint時にカーソルにピックボックスが表示できない

Tags: .net, vb.net, ijcad

GetPoint（GrxCAD.EditorInput.Editor.GetPoint）でユーザ指定の点を取得する際にマウスカーソルにピックボックスが表示されません。
PromptPointOptionsやDocumentのシステム変数（PICKBOX等）の設定・見直しを行っている最中なのですが、そもそもGetPoint時にピックボックスを表示することが可能なのでしょうか。

開発環境はVisual Staudio VB.net、IJCAD2016です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetPointメソッドは座標を入力する為のメソッドで、エンティティを選択する為のものではありませんので、ユーザ入力中にピックボックスは表示されません。